# Mentioning an experience in the CV

Tags: resume

Should someone mention an experience in his CV if the organization maintains low opinion about him?

Various reasons could be involved,

- Sacked by company for any valid reason
- Engaged in legal battle with the company
- Had feud with his superiors

and so on...

Comment: How would you explain the gap in your history?

Answer (score 2):

No, I can't see a positive reason for doing that. CV is your showpiece, nothing in it should indicate conflict or be detrimental to you if you can avoid it.

Comment: That said, you might have some explaining to do about a gap in your employment history if you worked for that organization for any significant length of time.